# Lose value of singleton

Tags: swift, singleton

I am making a call to a web-service and get a token back. I have tried different ways to safe this in globals variables and now tried a singleton. When I print the value immediately after I have set it I get the value but once I am out of the web service `URLSession.shared.dataTask` call and cll the resume the value in the singleton is gone. Below is my code, please note I am only doing swift now for a week :)

```
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8) 

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data ,response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = (response)")
        }

        // Get rid of ekstra escape chars
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        let newString = responseString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
        let newString2 = newString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"{", with: "{")
        let newString3 = newString2?.replacingOccurrences(of: "}\"", with: "}")
        let newdata = newString3?.data(using: .utf8)!

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: newdata!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
            Singleton.sharedInstance.setToken(Token: (json["SessionToken"] as? String)! )
            print(Singleton.sharedInstance.getToken()) // VALUE CORRECT

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }

        print(Singleton.sharedInstance.getToken()) // STILL GET THE CORRECT VALUE
    }
    task.resume()

    print(Singleton.sharedInstance.getToken()) // THE VALUE IS NOW NIL


class Singleton {
static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

var rToken:String?

func setToken( Token:String){
    let lToken = Token
    rToken = lToken
}

func getToken() -> String {

    if self.rToken != nil {
        return self.rToken!
    }

    return "0"
}
```

}

Comment: dataTask is executed asynchronously, thats why  print(Singleton.sharedInstance.getToken()) is nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As KeranMarinov points out the operation is completed asynchronously, so you are getting in to a race condition. Basically your request is taking longer to finish on the background thread than it takes for the main thread to step to the next line and check the value.

What you could do is dispatch your request on the main thread, and then check the value:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    myRequest()
 })
print(Singleton.sharedInstance.getToken())
```

Also, lets tidy up your sanitizing of the string:

```
let sanitizedData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "\"{", with: "{")
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "}\"", with: "}")
    .data(using: .utf8)!
```

Finally, you should also look in to [completion handlers](https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/), which is a good way to handle the effects of asynchronous behavior.